# How to check for duplicates in sentence using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

In finance you have something called a "CurrencyPair" (USD/GBP).
How can I create a regular expression that validate this so that the user is not entering the same currency twice (USD/USD)?

I have the following basic regexp to work with:

```
([A-Z]{3})/([A-Z]{3})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a negative lookahead and a backreference:

```
([A-Z]{3})/((?!\1)[A-Z]{3})
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/xF9cS5)

`(?! ... )` is a negative lookahead. If its contents match, the whole match will fail.

`\1` is a backreference referring to the first captured group.

Answer (score 2):

Use a backreference to the first capture group. Something like this:

```
([A-Z]{3})/\1
```

Comment: Read the question, he doesnt want the text to be the same :)

Comment: depends how he wants implements it. his validation can be "if matches, process data" in which case Jerry's solution is best, but if he wanted "if CurrencyPair is identical, display error abc" then my regex is preferable. of course for both of these, you could just invert the output.